# Using sympy to takes a list of expressions and return a list of number of times each expression intersect every other

Tags: python, sympy

I have a question, whereby you need to write write a function **num_intersections(expressions)** which takes a list of expressions as an argument and return a list of the number of times each expression in this list intersects with every other. Each expression should be written as a string and should contain only one symbol

Assume there will always be more than one expression within the list of expressions and no expression will be the same.

Notes:
`parse_expr()` is available for you to use in this function and sympy has been imported into this question as sp.

*Test*
`print(num_intersections(["x ** 2 - 1", "0.25 * x - 1"]))`

*Result*
`[2, 2]`

*Test*
`print(num_intersections(["x ** 2 - 1", "0.25 * x - 1", "x + 1"]))`

*Result*
`[4, 3, 3]`

I know it is similar to this:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
def check_intersection(exp1, exp2):
    """check intersection"""
    equ1= parse_expr(exp1)
    equ2= parse_expr(exp2)
    return len(sp.solve(equ1-equ2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get help here the code for anyone who needs it in the future.

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

def num_intersections(expressions):
    """intersection"""
    result=[]
    for exp in expressions:
        exp=parse_expr(exp)
        i=0
        for equ in expressions:
            equ=parse_expr(equ)
            if exp != equ:
                i+= len(sp.solve(exp-equ))
        result.append(i)
    return result
```